# How to find the shift parameter of a Butterworth filter?

Tags: signal-processing, butterworth

After experimentation, it look likes that Butterworth filter implies a shift of a certain number of points. I would like to know if there is a formula that connect the order of my filter ?

I am new to the theory of filters, and I would like to don't use a double filter, for commodity reason.

Thank you,

Comment: It's not that simple - "group delay" is what you're looking for, but different frequencies are delayed by different amounts. Try https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Phase_Group_Delay.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have taken a look, and understood lot of things. I am coming from pure math, hard training to get the vision of applied scientists =) if you know a good reference book that connect well with examples the two sides !